# c# - Get HTML Code as String with Windows 1252 Encoding

Tags: c#, html, mobile, encoding, uwp

I am working on an App for Windows Mobile.
Currently I am trying to get the HTML Source code from a webpage with Windows 1252  Encoding. While running the code below I'm always getting a "System.NotSupportedException". Can anybody help me?

The place it gets called:

```
private async void b_day1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int day = 1;
    await GetHTML(day);
}
```

The method "GetHTML(int day)":

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> GetHTML(int day)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response;
    if (day == 1)
    {
        response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.fsglb.de/fileadmin/stundenplaene/vplan/1.htm");
        var bytearray = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        string final = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(bytearray);
        Debug.WriteLine(final);
        return final;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly where do you get this extension (works on my machine...)?

Can you split the Encoding.GetEncoding and GetString to separate lines

`var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
      string final = encoding.GetString(bytearray);`

Comment: This code works for me well, possibly the problem is in the code that calls this one, can you share it?

Comment: I've edited the post...

Comment: Use this Use Encoding.Convert method. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdcak6ye.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the problem. I had to enable all Encodings with:

```
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
```

Comment: With .netstandard2.0 (and later) you will have to install the nuget package System.Text.Encoding.CodePages in order to get CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance.